When Robocopy has an error, it sometimes opens in a new cmd.exe windows, and sometimes it stays in the same PowerShell window. Why?
I use Robocopy in Windows PowerShell. When Robocopy has an error, it sometimes opens in a new cmd.exe windows, and sometimes it stays in the same PowerShell window. Why?

Example below with the command:
robocopy /e "M:\BackedUpInEHD-E" Z:/BackedUpInEHD-E

And the error:
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> robocopy /e "M:\BackedUpInEHD-E" Z:/BackedUpInEHD-E

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wednesday, September 25, 2024 3:15:56 PM
2024/09/25 15:15:56 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Getting File System Type of Source M:\BackedUpInEHD-E\
The system cannot find the path specified.

   Source = M:\BackedUpInEHD-E\
     Dest = Z:\BackedUpInEHD-E\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2024/09/25 15:15:56 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Accessing Source Directory M:\BackedUpInEHD-E\
The system cannot find the path specified.
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>

Sometimes Robocopy opens in a new cmd.exe windows:

Since the new cmd.exe windows opens and closes quickly, here is a screenshot of it:

Example where Robocopy stays in the same PowerShell window:

I use Windows 10 Pro 21H2. Both M and Z use the exFAT file system.

That's mysterious. robocopy.exe's output - as a Windows console-subsystem application - should always print to the current console (and that is indeed what I've only ever seen, across various Windows versions).

What happens if you run the same command from a local drive and folder that you know exists, e.g. from C:\?

I did notice the Z drive destination uses forward slash after colon and is not double quote enclosed unlike the E drive source in the command at least. I wonder if it's related to that but definitely seems bizarre. Might be worth mentioning the file system formats of both source and destination drives as well in case this rings any bells.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle thanks! "the file system formats of both source and destination drives" both exFAT
